# Render a different view if URL has a '.js' appended in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url, view

I'd like to render a normal HTML view if the URL is something like:

```
www.foo.com/scripts/view/23123
```

And I'd like to render a `Content` view if that URL ends with a `.js` extension.

```
www.foo.com/scripts/view/23123.js
```

---

How can I achieve something like this in ASP.Net MVC3?

Here's my controller code:

```
public ActionResult View(string id)
{
    var script = scriptRepository.FindById(id);

    if (true) // Help with this conditional.
    {
        return View(script);
    }
    else 
    {
        return Content(script.Content, "text/javascript");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Request.Path.EndsWith(".js", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Consider also that you could create a different route that ends with .js in the URL.